# Modern OOP vs Alan Kays OOP

Tags: object-oriented, programming-languages, paradigms

I've recently come to discover there's actually a strong amount of criticism towards what people refer to as "modern OOP" - often comparing it to either functional programming or Alan Kays' OOP.

Here's the question which got me thinking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409494/some-solid-oop-criticism

Wikipedia has a section about OOP criticism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Criticism

Coming from a computer engineering university degree, I did my fare share of programming and development classes. I've done Java and C++ in school as well as NodeJS, Python, Perl and PHP on my own time. In all of these languages (except for maybe Python), I either implemented some OOP or used libraries which did.

So what's the big deal against modern OOP (or OOP in general)? Why do so many people seemingly dislike and dismiss it?

Comment: This is a discussion topic. Probably one best had over libations. It is not a simple, direct question, nor well-suited to the Stack Exchange Q&A format.

Comment: Because of the [Blub paradox](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html), it's doubtful anyone would be able to explain how some other paradigm is better (as opposed to just *different*) without you actually learning that paradigm. Also, if you ask 10 people what OOP is, you're likely to get 10 different answers, so it's kind of impossible to answer the question without knowing your definition or whatever the "modern OOP" is.

Comment: @Doval: Assuming you accept the validity of the Blub Paradox.  Given that the concept comes from a developer with a strong bias for a failed language, who has never had any problem with stretching the truth well beyond the breaking point in order to support his cause, his self-serving, condescending ideas about developers who use other languages and their incapability to understand why they're wrong should be taken with a grain of salt, if not the entire shaker!

Comment: @MasonWheeler Well, it's not hard to find a bazillion questions like "what's the big deal with OOP, what's wrong with procedural programming", and I'm sure a handful of decades ago there were a ton of "what's the big deal with procedural programming, what's wrong with unrestricted GOTOs", so there's some truth to it independently of whether you drink the functional (or Lisp) Kool-Aid.

Comment: @Doval: Where?  I haven't heard anyone asking "why use OOP when we could just use procedural programming" since the turn of the century.  In many ways, OOP *is* procedural programming; the fundamental flow of control is exactly the same, except for virtual method dispatch, which is only slightly more complicated.  I've heard plenty of people ask "why use OOP over *functional* programming?" but that's a very, very different question!

Comment: @MasonWheeler [Here's one circa 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135535/what-are-the-benefits-of-oo-programming-will-it-help-me-write-better-code?lq=1) from a (procedural?) PHP programmer. [Here's another circa 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697898/advantages-of-oop?lq=1) that contrasts it with the use of non-abstract C structs. There's others linked on the side, and there's probably more still in Reddit, Lambda The Ultimate, JavaRanch, etc.

Answer (score 5):

First off, "modern OOP" is not a deviation from Alan Kay's OOP.  Kay may have coined the term itself, but Smalltalk-style "OOP" is a *significant* deviation from actual class-and-object programming as it existed before Smalltalk.  The original OOP system was called Simula, and it was an extended dialect of of ALGOL whose OOP concepts would feel right at home in modern languages such as Delphi, Java or C#.  The Smalltalk style is the aberration, and it's been a failure everywhere it's been tried.  (With the minor exception of Objective-C, whose popularity is due in its entirety to Apple shoving it down iOS developers' throats; outside of the Apple ecosystem its market share is essentially nil.)

As for the question, the biggest reason why many people criticize it is simple, old-fashioned "sour grapes."  Looking at the linked Wikipedia article, the critics it names are hardly objective: one is one of the principal guys behind ML, the other is the principal guy behind Erlang, both of which are languages that have failed in the "marketplace of ideas" while OOP has taken over the world.

> Luca Cardelli has claimed that OOP code is "intrinsically less efficient" than procedural code, that OOP can take longer to compile, and that OOP languages have "extremely poor modularity properties with respect to class extension and modification", and tend to be extremely complex.

`Intrinsically less efficient`?  Maybe, but it's also far more powerful.  The main intrinsic inefficiency comes from polymorphism: virtual dispatch requires more CPU cycles and is cache inefficient, but it can achieve some incredibly useful abstractions in return for this engineering tradeoff.  And I doubt that anyone trying to achieve the same thing in a procedural language without language-level support could do it in any way that turns out to be noticeably more efficient, so that's kind of a silly complaint.

`that OOP can take longer to compile`?  Ha! Try telling that to a Delphi developer.  It can literally compile code faster than the hard drive can serve it up.

`that OOP languages have "extremely poor modularity properties"`?  Try telling that to any Delphi, Java or .NET developer who uses the rich ecosystem of modular code that's been built up over the years on a daily basis.  This is simply not true.

`tend to be extremely complex`?  Well sure; they're solving complex problems.  You can't make essential complexity disappear; you can add abstraction and sweep it under the rug, but [that will come back to bite you at some point, guaranteed.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html)

Bottom line: if OOP didn't work well, *it wouldn't work well.*  And then no one would be using it because it just doesn't work.  But a simple glance at the reality of the programming world puts the lie to that concept.

Comment: Mainstream OOP languages *do* have poor module systems. In particular, they force you to hard-code a reference to every non-`interface` data type you want to use. If there's two `class`es `X` and `Y` identical in every way except their name, you can't substitute one for the other. You can get some substitutability by renaming Y.java to X.java and replacing the file, but that still limits any software system to at most one copy of that abstraction. The end result is that everyone ends up declaring an `interface` for most of the abstractions in the system, but that casts a wider net...

Comment: ...than necessary, because now anyone can introduce a bogus implementation of the `interface` if they want to, and when the software explodes because of it you have to figure out which implementation of the interface caused the failure; as opposed to a reference to a `class`, which always points to an instance of that type or at best a subclass. `interface`s also don't support binary methods, which is why you don't see methods like `union` in Java's `Set` interfaces, because there's no way to guarantee that the second set is an instance of the same class.

Comment: @Doval: Poor workmen blame their tools.  If you have two classes that are identical in every way except their name, then your problem isn't that your language won't let you use them interchangeably; it's that **you have two classes that are identical in every way except their name**.

Comment: @doval - doesn't Go allow those to be drop in replacement? A structural type system would allow that and is orthogonal to OO otherwise. Though to be fair, common OO implementations don't do that.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Sure, but the converse is not true - from the fact that someone blames his tools, you can't conclude he's a poor workman. I'm just stating facts - common OOP languages have modularity limitations that can be overcome. I'm not saying that it's impossible to write good software in those languages or whatever it is you're projecting on detractors of OOP languages. I think SML is a better language than Java (opinion, not fact) but I'm not daft enough to assert that that's enough to outweigh Java's ubiquity or the fact that SML has no real IDEs and few production quality libraries.

Comment: @Telastyn You're correct, it's an orthogonal issue, and the fact that most successful languages lack the feature is probably just the result of historical inertia.

Comment: @Doval: Sure, there are plenty of languages better than Java, but that's because the Java language itself is pretty mediocre; not because there are serious problems with the underlying OOP concepts.  (Surely any developer understands the distinction between a bad idea and a poor implementation of a fundamentally good idea!)

Comment: @MasonWheeler I don't disagree, but Harper (the ML guy) attacked OOP *languages*. (I'm fairly convinced he writes flame bait on purpose even if I think there's some truth to it.) The whole OOP *concept* thing is murky. [Objects are only one of two tools for abstraction](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf), but depending on who you ask abstract data types are the same thing as objects or also fall within the purview of OOP, and that's before getting into using mutation, which is technically orthogonal to using objects but almost always accompanies it.

Comment: Suffice to say that I don't think OOP is all bad, but I don't think all the good bits are necessarily related to objects either, nor do I think the best of OOP is all that different from functional programming, for certain definitions of OOP and functional programming.

Comment: @Doval: That is a *bizarre* article, and the author has an extremely poor concept of object-oriented programming.  What he calls "Abstract data types" are, in fact, objects and classes, except that he seems ignorant of the existence of `interface` types that solve the "inherent" problems in the ADT system he describes.  And what he calls "objects" are not OOP at all, but appear to be some bizarre system based on lambda calculus and functional programming.  If anyone's using this as the foundation of a criticism of OOP, no wonder they get confused! o_0

Comment: @MasonWheeler What he calls an object corresponds to an `interface`; `class`es are ADTs. For instance, he mentions that ADTs have a type that's known but whose representation is hidden. That's the case for a `class` whose members are all private; e.g. I know there exists some type `ArrayList` but I don't know how it's implemented internally. The type system can tell `ArrayList` values apart from instances of `MyCustomArrayList` even if the latter exposes the exact same API. An object on the other hand is simply some collection of functions, and doesn't expose its backing type...

Comment: ... e.g. given an instance of an `interface`, I have no idea what type is backing it (without using `instanceof`, which breaks abstraction.) You can implement an "object" in any language with closures by simply creating a bunch of closures that share the same data. The point is, the pros and cons of ADTs and objects (or `class`es and `interface`s) are dual. One's pros are the other's cons. The fact that you can't substitute one `class` for another in Java/C# is simply an implementation detail/flaw; it can be done in other languages.

Comment: Well garbage collection was invented back in the 1960s, but it wasn't used by most people until Java/C#.  So were higher-order functions, lexical scope was pioneered by Scheme I believe.  So back in the 1990s or 1980s you could have asked:  if higher-order functions, lexical scope, REPL, and OOP were so good why doesn't anyone use them?

Comment: Although IMHO Alan Kay's initial idea of message passing, which allows for potential async "function call" and distributed computing, deserves a place in the history of computing, this post is damn brave and right to point out the deviation of Alan Kay's OOP from early (thus more orthodox) as well as modern OOP. Within the current context of OOP, I think Dr. Kay's exclusive contribution is primarily the term OOP.